# JavaScript Pass button id to an asp.net hiddenfield

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net

I got a silly question just as the question stated,the failed code shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HISenlarge(id) {
    var parent = id;
    document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value = parent;
 }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button"  id="kkkk" onclick="HISenlarge(this.id)"></button>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" value=""/>
```

VBcode

```
 Protected Sub CommentButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CommentButton.Click
    Dim c_id As String
    c_id = HiddenField1.Value.ToString
```

Comment: What is error you got?

Comment: there is nothing in the hiddenField

Comment: Have you checked what value of "id" you are getting inside the HISenlarge function ?

Comment: `document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value= parent;` ?

Comment: works thanks Nagaraj S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value = parent;`

This is not a HTML for the `HiddenField1`.So you should reference it by its `ClientID`

`document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value= parent;`